# Gleemax targeting

Tags: magic-the-gathering, house-rules, mtg-joke-cards

Does [Gleemax](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGleemax%5d) allow you to choose an invalid target for a spell or ability?  If you have it on the field and the other player plays and spell that say choose 2 creatures you control and place a +1/+1 token on them.  Can you choose a creature you control or do you have to choose one of their creatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

Keep in mind Silver-Bordered games always require some play-group-specific interpretation of the rules.

That being said, Gleemax changes who selects the targets, but it does not change anything about the legality of choosing targets. Player B selecting a creature they control for player A's ability that must target 'a creature you control' is illegal because the qualifier for the target refers to player A, so it effectively means 'a creature player A controls'.

Comment: That is why I used the house rules tag and understand that

Comment: Well, house rules by definition will always be up to the groups interpretation, so we won't be able to give a definite answer. My point was that nothing in Gleemax's text changes legality of target selection, so this would be a new clause. If your group wants to add new rules (or rather, take them away for Gleemax), you're free to do so. To get this effect, I would suggest adding additional wording like 'Requirements for targets may be ignored.'

Comment: @Aetherfox I mean, by that logic any game or Magic format can have interpretations. If you need Magic help, you ask a judge. If you need silver border help, you ask Mark Rosewater on blogatog who does often give official silver border help. Silver border, while a bit silly, is not any more or less ambiguous than black border. *queue joke about Ambiguity here*